# Appending a string to a file from remote ssh

Tags: ssh, text-processing, echo

I want to ssh to a node (which is passwordless) and append `$spool_as_final_name true` to a file `/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config`. Note that is mandatory to put `$` in front of the string.

So, I wrote

```
ssh node01 "echo \"\$spool_as_final_name true\" >> /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config"
```

However the file looks like

```
Dummy
 true
```

I intentionally wrote Dummy to show you that `true` is written in the second column.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use,

```
ssh node1 'echo "\$spool_as_final_name true" >> /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config'
```

Or you can use the `cat` command,

```
echo "\$spool_as_final_name true" | ssh node1 "cat >> /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config"
```